# At what level should you retrieve data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a section of my app that displays data in the structure below. When a user clicks on filter, the data changes.

It's a common case, but it's unclear to me where I should be executing an API call for the data and why I should be doing it there.

(a) I could do it on the outer most container and pass it into the white section then finally a component that creates the rows of data.
(b) I could do it in the white section and then pass it into a component that creates the rows.
(c) I could call for it in the component that creates the rows of data.

I think I may be missing a fundamental understanding about React that is making this unclear to me because even after trying them out, none seem obvious.

[image: data container]

Comment: [This article](https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/client-side-architecture/introduction/) is a little long but its well worth the read. Maybe it can clear things up a little bit.

Comment: @RedFox thank you, this was very helpful. I know it doesn't doesn't directly answer my question, but ultimately it's the answer I needed.

Answer (score 3):

React's great strength is its ability to create components that are easily reusable.

In your case, in my opinion, the best thing to do is to make your API call in the container of your section, i.e. the white area that contains the title, the filter and your table.

This way you can reuse your table component and your filter component for other containers.

It will give you something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
}

getData = (param = "") => {
    // Make your api call here and save your data in the state of the component for example
}

applyFilter = param => this.getData(param);

render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    return (
        <div>
            <MyTitle />
            <MyFilter applyFilter={this.applyFilter} />
            <MyTable rows={data} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on when you actually want to load the data. If that "rows of data" is a standalone component, then you can write an `useEffect` hook with an empty array as the dependency list, so when your component is rendered for the first time, you can have all the data.

In case you aren't familiar with Hooks, you can do it in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. Make sure to fill the dependency array with any dependencies related to the API call in case you are using hooks.

Comment: What is my decision about "when" based on? It seems to me that I could load it at the outer most level or the inner most level (before the rows themselves) and accomplish the same thing. I understand how these can be done, but the "why" and "when" regarding structure is unclear to me.